# How to group different variables in a csv?

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to create a script which restarts about 20 PCs at a time. I have a list with all the PC's and their location and I want to be able to restart them depending on their location.

```
Write-Host "Enter your Admin credentials:"
$UserCredential = Get-Credential

Write-Host "1 = Alle"
Write-Host "2 = TMU"
Write-Host "3 = TMH"
Write-Host "4 = TIN"
Write-Host "5 = TWO"

$query = Read-Host -Prompt "Which group should be started?"

if ($query -eq "1"){

    $1csv = Import-Csv -Path '.\All.csv' -Delimiter ";"

    ForEach ($computername in $1csv) {

        Write-Host "Following PC is getting restarted: " -NoNewline
        Write-Host $computername.computername

        Restart-Computer -Computername $computername.computername -Credential $UserCredential -Force
    }
}
```

This script worked for me, but I had to depend on 5 csv. files. Now I want it to be in a single one. Like:

computername        location

Pc1                 munich

Pc2                 berlin

Pc3                 frankfurt

Pc4                 munich

...

But I don't know a sulution on how to group the location "munich" and address it. Or to address every PC who has the location "munich"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to filter your object array based on property values, you technically only need `Where` or `Where-Object`. If all of your data is in `All.csv` with `computername` and `location` headers, you can do the following:

```
$1csv = Import-Csv -Path '.\All.csv' -Delimiter ";"
$computers = ($1csv | Where location -eq 'munich').computername

Restart-Computer -ComputerName $computers -Credential $UserCredential -Force
```

Since `-ComputerName` can accept an array, you do not need to run it for each computer in a list unless you want to treat each reboot individually.

Comment: Thank you! I went with your sulotion since It was the best for my case you really helped me out here and made me understand so much more about Powershell. This was my first script I ever created and I feel so proud even though I had to ask many times :D

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Group-Object`, I believe. For multiple CSVs:

```
$csv = Get-ChildItem .\All*csv | %{ Import-Csv $_ -Delimiter ";" }
$csv | Group-Object location
```

Will give you

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    4 munich                    {@{computername=Pc1; location=munich}, @{computername=Pc4; location=munich}, @{...
    2 berlin                    {@{computername=Pc2; location=berlin}, @{computername=Pc2; location=berlin}}
    2 frankfurt                 {@{computername=Pc3; location=frankfurt}, @{computername=Pc3; location=frankfurt}}
```

If you want to iterate over these, you can filter as well.

```
$csv | Group-Object location | Where-Object Name -Eq "munich" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group
```

Which will give you back the objects you passed into `Group-Object`

```
computername location
------------ --------
Pc1          munich
Pc4          munich
Pc1          munich
Pc4          munich
```

Comment: I only want to have a single CVS file. But thank you.

Comment: It works the same for a single file, you just don't populate `$csv` with a `gci` call.

Comment: Thank you very much! Helped me alot <3